# How to code: "If (A is True) and (B is True when C is True)"

Tags: if-statement

How do I code this if statement (let's say in c++):

```
if (condition1 == true and condition2 == true (when condition3 == true))
{
    // condition2 need to be true only when condition3 is true
}
```

Comment: Using `&&` and parentheses...

Comment: Your question title has `A`, `B`, and `C` but your code sample has `condition1`, `condition2`, and `condition3` and the logic doesn't match.

Comment: You should draw a truth-table, because if `C == false` then your statement will never be evaluated, but you worded your question as though `B` matters when `C == false`, but I don't see how or why.

Answer (score 0):

When figuring out how to express any boolean-predicate it helps to [build a **truth-table** that lists the possible values of each boolean value in separate columns and the expected output in its own column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table). The values in each column increment by `+1` as though each column is a binary-digit in a base-2 number.

Like so:

```
A    B    C    Output
---------------------
0    0    0    ?
0    0    1    ?
0    1    0    ?
0    1    1    ?
1    0    0    ?
1    0    1    ?
1    1    0    ?
1    1    1    ?
```

Based on your question's title (and not the example pseudocode that you posted), I assume you want this output:

```
A    B    C    Output
---------------------
0    0    0    0
0    0    1    0
0    1    0    0
0    1    1    0
1    0    0    0
1    0    1    0
1    1    0    0
1    1    1    1
```

...which is just a trivial `AND` between all 3 values:

```
bool a = ...
bool b = ...
bool c = ...

if( a && b && c )
{
    do_the_thing();
}
```